# Searching and sorting is not working in ignited datatables

Tags: php, codeigniter, sorting, search, datatables

I am using Ignited Datatables in my codeigniter application. Everything is working except searching and sorting. My code is like:
Controller page:

```
public function datatable()
    {
          $this->datatables->select("
               insight_project.projectName projectName,
               insight_project_module.moduleName moduleName,
               insight_project_submodule.subModuleName issueName,
               insight_project_submodule.estimatedTime estimatedTime,
               insight_worksheet.spentTime,
               insight_activity_list.name activityName,
               insight_status.name statusName,
               insight_worksheet.completedPercentage,
               insight_worksheet.updatedById,
               insight_worksheet.activity worksheetFillUpDate,
               insight_worksheet.projectId workingDate,
               insight_worksheet.reason,
               insight_worksheet.worksheet_status
            ")
          ->from("insight_worksheet")
          ->join("insight_project_module","project_module.id=worksheet.moduleId","left")
          ->join("insight_project","project.id=worksheet.projectId","left")
          ->join("insight_project_submodule","project_submodule.id=worksheet.submoduleId","left")
        ->join("insight_activity_list","activity_list.id=worksheet.activity","left")
       ->join("insight_status","status.id=worksheet.status","left");

      echo $this->datatables->generate();
    }
```

and in the view page the datatables plugin related code is there. 
I have included jquery library file and jquery.dataTables.min.js.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var oTable = $('#big_table').dataTable({
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": '<?php echo site_url() ?>/worksheet/datatable',
             "sDom": '<"H"Tlpf>rt<"F"ip>',
             "aoColumns": [
                {"bSearchable": true,"bSortable": true},
                {"bSearchable": true,"bSortable": true},
                {"bSearchable": true,"bSortable": true},
                {"bSearchable": true,"bSortable": true},
                {"bSearchable": true,"bSortable": true},
                {"bSearchable": true,"bSortable": true},
                {"bSearchable": true,"bSortable": true},
                {"bSearchable": true,"bSortable": true},
                {"bSearchable": true,"bSortable": true},
                {"bSearchable": true,"bSortable": true},
                {"bSearchable": true,"bSortable": true},
                {"bSearchable": true,"bSortable": true},
                {"bSearchable": true,"bSortable": true}
          ],

            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "iDisplayStart ": 20,
            "oLanguage": {
                "sProcessing": 
               "<img 
                     src='<?php echo base_url(); ?>Assets/images/ajax-loader_dark.gif' 
                    alt='processing_srimanta'>"
            },            
            "fnInitComplete": function () {
               // oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
            },
            'fnServerData': function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                aoData.push({
                     name: '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>', 
                    value: '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'});
                $.ajax
                ({
                    'dataType': 'json',
                    'type': 'POST',
                    'url': sSource,
                    'data': aoData,
                    'success': fnCallback
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<?php echo $this->table->generate(); ?>
```

But searching and column sorting is not working.
Please let me know what is my issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please remove `bServerSide` initialization option and see if sorting and searching works.

Comment: Done. The problem is for column alias name, if I remove the alias name it is working fine. But please let me know if possible with the column alias name.